# inner join showing wrong date in where query?

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

Using where clause in inner join but inner join is not selecting what I asked for in query. Here I am to select only 12-jun data whereas innerjoin query selecting previous date data aswell.

[image: My Table]

QUERY IS:

```
SELECT
    p_sale_inv.datetime,
    p_sale_inv.sale_inv,
    p_sale_inv.Jobber,
    p_sale_part.stock_id,
    p_sale_part.quantity,
    p_sale_part.netamount,
    p_purch_stock.Price,
    p_sale_part.sale_inv
FROM
    p_sale_inv
INNER JOIN p_sale_part ON p_sale_inv.sale_inv = p_sale_part.sale_inv
INNER JOIN p_purch_stock ON p_sale_part.stock_id = p_purch_stock.stock_id
WHERE
    DATE_FORMAT(p_sale_inv.datetime, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2018-07-12' AND '2018-07-12'
```

[AND RESULT IS:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqCnP.png)

PROBLEM IS:
Why query showing same date? In actual as you can see above table they are different.

Comment: You see how the query isn't a picture? The table and result needn't be pictures either.

Comment: If you want to get only 12-jun data, why your query selects **BETWEEN '2018-07-11' AND '2018-07-12'** ??? You are selecting 11 and 12 of July. If you just want 12-jun, you can use **DATE_FORMAT(p_sale_inv.datetime, '%Y-%m-%d')='2018-06-12'**

Comment: No i have to select from daterange and here i was trying different things so forget to change it, 12-07 to 12-07

Comment: @Strawberry i wanted to give pics but its says you need to have 10 score and I have only 6 :(

Comment: Don't give pics.

Comment: ok sir, as you ordered

Comment: Get rid of the images & links please, use text for text, including tables. Also read & act on [mcve]. Also "query showing same date" & "they are different" are not clear. Use enough words & sentences to be clear.